# How to use header and footer in android

Tags: android, header, navigation, footer

I am developing an app in android in which I need a  header and footer through out app **while switching between different activities**. The header and footer text will change while switching between activities. What would be the best way to achieve this approach? Actually the header will show navigation of app.

Comment: I want to know how to use header and footer so that it would be static in whole app. I do not want to create them on each next activity. So that when switch between activities only internal content should switch from right to left not the header and footer

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to create them on each next activity. So that when switch between activities only internal content should switch from right to left not the header and footer

This is not possible with separate activities, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could recreate what a [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) does? So you'll load your activities in your "raiActivity", and instead of having various tabs, you'll have a header and footer.

Check out [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) for this

Answer (score 0):

May work with

> fragments

but i don't know how to explain it to you. Google search tutorials for fragments and even frame layout maube you get what you want. This was the closest i got to answer my questions about something like that.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?